# How do I delay an event in Kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to capture text from a Text Input box and fire off a function after the text is inputted. Only problem is the event is fired everytime a character is entered. I would like the event fired after all characters have been entered in the text input box. How could i delay the firing until all characters have been entered?

I tried to override the on_text method but did not solve my problem as it is this method that is being called 20 times. I also tried putting in a sleep in the on_text but it just buffered the responses and still fired 20 times.

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what you're already doing, but have the function you're calling check if whatever condition you're after is met. For instance, if you want to call it after 5 characters have been entered, check the length of the string.

This seems an awkward way of working though, are you sure you want to check after every character rather than, say, wait for the user to press enter?

Comment: I wouldn't want to check after every character. It's going to be a barcode scan, i just want it to check after the entire barcode is done being scanned. I want it automated so after the last character is entered it fires off a function. I figure i could use the on_text method for this. The issue is is that the event is fired after every character is entered. So when I call my function from on_text the function gets called for every character entered. .Also the barcodes are of varying length.

Comment: Right, but the point is what *does* mean the barcode is ready? When do you want to call the function? How do you know when the last character is entered? You have to answer this question to yourself, then write some code to act based on whatever the answer was.